# Allow double quotes (speech marks) in php string when doing string replace

Tags: php, regex, string

i am trying to find a quicker method of replacing all double quotes with single in my string.

I have a large amount of html echo'd out with PHP but now want to wrap this html in double quotes so i can just use the variable instead of having to wrap it in '.$string.' etc.

So i quickly wrote this:

```
$string = "test '""'fweffwf""'dwfwfe";

$string = str_replace('"', "'", $string);

echo $string;
```

But it breaks because i guess it thinks i am closing the string when it comes across a "

The html i already have is fairly chunky and i have more to do in the future and dont want to manually change each one.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I think `"\""` was inherited from C++.

Comment: You can escape a `"` in PHP using a backslash: `\ ` so for example: `$string = "test \"i am in quotes\" end";`

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `htmlspecialchars` to sanitize the data instead of trying to convert quotes and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If escaping quotes becomes difficult, you can use the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$string = <<<EOD
test '""'fweffwf""'dwfwfe
EOD;

echo $string;
```

This outputs:

```
test '""'fweffwf""'dwfwfe
```

Comment: Works, shall have a look into the heredoc syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be,

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
test '""'fweffwf""'dwfwfe
EOT;
$pattern = "~\"~";
$replacement = "'";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> test ''''fweffwf'''dwfwfe
```

Don't forget to escape the double quotes present inside the `$pattern` variable.